# Regular expression that checks if characters are escaped

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to create the following rule in java: if a string contains a < or > the character before must be a \ (like checking if < and > are escaped).

Can anyone tell me a regular expression that finds strings where the \ is missing?

Thank you.

PS: It must be a regular expression, no indexOf() etc.

Comment: Did you attempt a solution already yourself? Or do you just want someone to come along and propose a solution for you

Comment: Can ``\`` escape also another characters like itself? I am interested if string like `\<` and `\\<` are possible where `\<` represents escaped `<` and in `\\<` ``\`` is producing escaped ``\`` (literal) and unescaped `<`.

Comment: `"PS: It must be a regular expression, no indexOf() etc."` sounds like homework to me. Have you attempted to come up with a solution on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the below regex,

```
(?<!\\)[<>]
```

This would match `<` or `>` when it's not preceded by `\`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jQ6uC6/4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this negative lookbehind based regex:

```
(?<!\\)[<>]
```

#### [Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iF3xG5/1)

Answer (score 0):

[Look behind you!](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

You can do it like:

```
/(?<!\\)(<|>)/
```